# Two Eclipse Android Projects: One is a widget, one is a normal app. How to connect?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I've looked at the help on the development site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Downside is, my code can't find my app's class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, <package for main activity>.MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);
```

The package for MainActivity is in an entirely different project in Eclipse.

So I added the package for MainActivity to the build path for my widget, and put it in the front of the order.

Build order:

-->main activity package<--

Widget/src

Widget/gen

Android 4.2.2

Android Dependencies

The App is already on my emulator, and works fine.

The widget works fine without trying to connect to the App (so without those 4 lines up there)

Here's what I get when I tyr to connect the two, and install onto emulator:

[Widget] ------------------------------

[Widget] Android Launch!

[Widget] adb is running normally.

[Widget] No Launcher activity found!

[Widget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

[Widget] Performing sync

[Widget] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'NexusS'

[Widget] Uploading Widget.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[Widget] Installing Widget.apk...

[Widget] Success!

[Widget] Project dependency found, installing: MainActivity

[MainActivity] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.

[Widget] /Widget/bin/Widget.apk installed on device

[Widget] Done!

The widget is thrown on, but doesn't work. Shows only default string values. There is an error in the code on the line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, <package for main activity>.MainActivity.class);
```

That basically says "class not found"

Any help on how to get this class? Is Eclipse not making the .class file before trying to link it?

Note that eclipse has 0 problems with this code. It does recognize that the other project has been imported, and the class can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Google has fantastic documentation.  You're probably going to want to reveal your data with a content provider:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html